# Get row position within a series of records in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following rows within a table.

```
MatchIDAuto CompetitionIDAuto   TeamHome    TeamAway      MatchDate
4770          65                New Zealand South Africa 2017-02-19
4771          65                New Zealand South Africa 2017-02-21
4772          65                New Zealand South Africa 2017-02-25
4773          65                New Zealand South Africa 2017-03-01
4774          65                New Zealand South Africa 2017-03-04
```

What I need to be able to do is when I do the following:

```
select * from Match2 where MatchIDAuto=4772
```

Is know that it is the 3rd Match in the series. How could I dynamically calculate that with the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without an `ORDER BY` clause there is no guarantee that row with id `4772` is the third row in the serie. That is because the database without an order by clause MAY generate different orders accordingly the Execution Plan.

So the first thing to do is to add an order by clause to your query. By the data it could be `MatchIDAuto` or `MatchDate` that I will leave by your choice. The query in MySql to get you the order number of a row will be:

```
select * 
  from (
    select m.*, 
           @ord:=@ord+1 roworder 
      from Match2 m, 
           (select @ord:=0) t 
     ORDER BY MatchDate
    ) sub
  where MatchIDAuto=4772;
```

This will return every column plus `roworder` with the order 3. On this query I choose the `MatchDate` field since, to me makes more sense on your data to be the column of your order by.

This technique will create a variable and sums it up to every row. You just wrap it in a subquery and query it.